# Status 400 for AJAX POST Request with admin-ajax.php

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, ajax, javascript

I've been on this problem since yesterday, writing and rewriting my code to fix this 400 XRH error.
I cannot find a way to fix it.

Before showing you the code, here's some context:

I am trying to add variable products onto the archive loop. I've successfully brought the variation select form there and I can send the correct data with AJAX. The issue seems to be with the request.

Here's my code:

```php
// The main php function

function variation_add_to_cart_product(){

    $product_id = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint($_POST['product_id']));
    $quantity = empty($_POST['quantity']) ? 1 : wc_stock_amount($_POST['quantity']);
    $variation_id = absint($_POST['variation_id']);
    $passed_validation = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity);
    $product_status = get_post_status($product_id);

    if ($passed_validation && WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, $variation_id) && 'publish' === $product_status) {

            do_action('woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product_id);

            if ('yes' === get_option('woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add')) {
                    wc_add_to_cart_message(array($product_id => $quantity), true);
            }

            WC_AJAX :: get_refreshed_fragments();
    } else {

            $data = array(
                    'error' => true,
                    'product_url' => apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', get_permalink($product_id), $product_id));

            echo wp_send_json($data);
    }

    wp_die();

}
```

```php
// Its actions

add_action( 'wp_ajax_variation_add_to_cart_product', 'variation_add_to_cart_product' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_variation_add_to_cart_product', 'variation_add_to_cart_product' );

// The loading of the javascript file and the ajax url

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'vl_load_js_script' );

function vl_load_js_script() {
    wp_register_script('vl_script', plugins_url( 'js/vl-js.js', __FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_script('vl_script');

    $vl_ajax_array = array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    );

    // pass Ajax Url to script.js
    wp_localize_script('vl_script', 'vl_script', $vl_ajax_array );
}
```

```js
// The jQuery AJAX function

jQuery(function ($) {

  // Targeting the variation add_to_cart button
  $(document).on('click', '.vl_add_to_cart_button', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Selecting the clicked button
    var $thisbutton = $(this),
      // Selecting the variation form
      $form = $thisbutton.parents('.woo-entry-inner').find('.woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-enabled'),
      // Selecting the variation's product id
      product_id = $form.find('input[name=product_id]').val(),
      // Selecting the variation's id
      variation_id = $form.find('input[name=variation_id]').val(),
      // Selecting the variation's quantity
      variation_qty = $form.find('input[name=variation_qty]').val();

    // Creating the data array to send the data
    var data = {
      action: 'vl_ajax_add_to_cart',
      product_id: product_id,
      product_sku: '',
      quantity: variation_qty,
      variation_id: variation_id,
    };

    $(document.body).trigger('adding_to_cart', [$thisbutton, data]);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: vl_script.ajax_url,
      data: data,
      beforeSend: function (response) {
        $thisbutton.removeClass('added').addClass('loading');
      },
      complete: function (response) {
        $thisbutton.addClass('added').removeClass('loading');
      },
      success: function (response) {

        if (response.error && response.product_url) {
          window.location = response.product_url;
          return;
        } else {
          $(document.body).trigger('added_to_cart', [response.fragments, response.cart_hash, $thisbutton]);
        }
      },
    });

    return false;
  });

});
```

The request payload sent is `action=vl_ajax_add_to_cart&product_id=3468&product_sku=&quantity=5&variation_id=5249`.

The response is `0`.

The ajax address is `localhost/biotruck/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`.

Comment: I see you're using the old `admin-ajax.php` API, that API isn't very friendly to debug, and doesn't give readable error messages. Have you considered using the new REST API endpoints? It would give you a pretty permalink URL to send AJAX requests to, and if there was a problem it would tell you what that problem is in a human readable message. The main change you'd need to make is to replace `echo wp_send_json($data);` with `return $data` and too swap `$_POST` references to instead use the variable it gives you

Comment: I'll give it a try, thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared this:

```
wp_ajax_variation_add_to_cart_product
```

But then used this:

```
action: 'vl_ajax_add_to_cart',
```

Revealing the problem:

`variation_add_to_cart_product` != `vl_ajax_add_to_cart`

These 2 must match, and they do not.

Comment: That's was it! Thank you very much Tom!